# Java Hex string to BitSet

Tags: java

What is the best and simplest way using Java of converting a string such as `0xBD3E9110` into a `BitSet` such as `1011 1101 0011 1110 1001 0001 0001 0000`? That is, a method of the form:

```
public BitSet hexStringToBitSet(String hexString) {
   //...
}
```

I'd like to obtain a `BitSet` so that I can use `get(i)` to obtain the `true`/`false` value of each of the returned 32 bits.

Comment: define the values in a map then split the string

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work.

```
public static BitSet hexStringToBitSet(String hexString) {
    return BitSet.valueOf(new long[]{Long.valueOf(hexString.substring(2), 16)});
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BitSet bitSet = hexStringToBitSet("0xBD3E9110");
    System.out.println(bitSet);
}
```

Comment: That assumes the value is limited to a value that fits a `long`, e.g. `"0xBD3E9110BD3E9110BD3E9110BD3E9110BD3E9110"` won't work.

Comment: @Andreas The words `of each of the returned 32 bits` are tucked away at the end of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexbinary));
```

Comment: For those looking at this recently, `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` is no longer available in JDK 11.

Answer (score 0):

Look up BitSet in the [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). There, you will find several methods for creating a BitSet of the required value. Perhaps [valueOf(long[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf(long[])) will be the easiest to use in your case, even though you only need one element rather than a whole array, and you want an int, but a long is also ok. You can create a long using `Long.decode(String)` then put that into a one-element array and pass it to BitSet. You'll only need the first 32 bits of the BitSet.

Answer (score 0):

```
public BitSet hexStringToBitSet(String hexString) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for(int i = 0; i < hexString.length() - 1; i += 2) {
        String data = s.substring(i, i + 2);
        bout.write(Integer.parseInt(data, 16));
    }
    return BitSet.valueOf(bout.toByteArray());
}
```